# Conversion of 2 bit signed integer to 8 bit signed integer in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, types, type-conversion, data-conversion

I want to know how can we convert a set of samples with datatype "2 bit integer" to "8 bit integer" without loosing the information inside the samples? In my case I have this set of digital samples coming out from a " 2 bit ADC.

I also read somewhere that we can do it but we have to keep bit values in mind. Usually there is a table which says what are the bit values, these may be -3, -1, 1,3 or -1 , 0, 1, 2 or anything. So when you convert, you should keep them in mind in conversion.

I am not able to understand what this exactly mean?

Comment: I was not aware that matlab has a `2 bit integer` datatype. Are theses `fi` input/output objects inside your function? Have you checked the `cast` matlab function? However, increasing the bit width should not result in a information loss.

Comment: I don't have any function yet. To describe, I Have an analog signal which is digitized by a 2 bit ADC. And I have a function in which I should use this digital output. Also my function only handles 8 bit integer values but I am wondering what will be the datatype of sample results from a  2 bit ADC? And I also wanted to know how can I convert this 2-bit ADC output to 8-bit integer in order to use it in my function.

Comment: Quick question: are you doing this in real time? And have you already imported / streamed the data into matlab? Your question is missing alot of details. This way it will be very difficult to help you. We dont know at this moment what exactly your input is and what you have tried so far ...

Comment: No i am not doing it in real time. For now I will do post processing on this data. I haven't imported it to MATLAB yet. Because I am not sure about the datatype of the data that I have from this 2 bit ADC. I will use fseek and fread command on my file to import it in MATLAB. and there i need to mention the datatype. For example : signal_bb = fread (fid, 3000000, 'in8') Here i mention int8, as the data i had was received by a USRP where i set the datatype to be 8-bit integer.

Comment: As you see yourself there is (still) a lot of information missing ... nevertheless, you should research yourself more about fixed point numbers. you will see that increasing the bit width will not result in a information loss. (as pointed out in my first comment). For the future when asking a question please read [ask]

Comment: Okay Thank you. Now, I at least know that increasing bit width will not result into information loss. Now I will read on how can we increase bit width.

Comment: Ignore the data types and just work with the values . If it is a 2-bit ADC, probably only allowed values are -1,0,1.  When you start doing the calculations ignoring data type and have some code, if you still have problems post that code and tell us what your problem is.